# how to evaluate a .py file with built-in input function?

Tags: python

let say I have a .py file which get input with python built-in input function and I want to give this file multi inputs and process its output automatically.(built-it input function get input from keyboard)
how can I do this?

Comment: In shell, `input.txt > main.py` will pass `input.txt`'s contents into standard input to `main.py`.

Comment: @BoseongChoi **Don't do that!** That will attempt to **run input.txt** as an executable, **truncating main.py**. You want `main.py < input.txt`. BTW please don't post answers in the comments. If you had posted an answer, I would have edited it to fix it for you.

Comment: It would really help if you provided a short example of the Python file and how you use it, similar to a [mre].

Comment: Is this on Windows, Linux, or something else?

Comment: @wjandrea my mistake. Thank you for correction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, let's say your Python file is called `hello.py` and looks like this:

```
print('Hello', input())
```

You can run it from the command line like this:

```
$ python3 hello.py
William
Hello William
```

Now say you have your name stored in `name.txt`. You can have the shell read it into your script's standard input (stdin) with `<` like this:

```
$ python3 hello.py < name.txt
Hello William
```